# Java email validation (No regex allowed)

Tags: java, validation, email

I need to write an email validation script. It needs to take the email typed in from the user and verify is certain criteria are met and give a true/false. Regex is NOT allowed.

//This is my scanner:

```
Scanner isValidEmail = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter your email: ");
String email = isValidEmail.nextLine();
```

I now need to check using various methods is it has letters, numbers, underscore, only 1 @, etc.

I have written booleans to verify those (examples):

//methos isValidPrefixChar to verify character

```
public static boolean isValidPrefixChar(char a) {
    if (isAlphanumeric(a) || a == '-' || a == '_' || a == '.') {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

//method getDomain() that takes as input a String representing a possible email address.

```
public static String getDomain(String possibleEmail) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < possibleEmail.length(); i++) {
        if (possibleEmail.charAt(i) == '@') {
            break;
        }
    }
//use a loop to have the character from second half
        String domain = "";
        int k = i + 1;
        while (k < possibleEmail.length()) {
            domain = domain + possibleEmail.charAt(k);
            k++;
        }
        return domain;
    }
```

And I have some code that doesn't yet work...

However, I need help in getting the email the user typed in to be the string that gets verified. How do I get the code to check my 'isValidEmail' for these requirements?

EDIT:
Unfortunately, I need to validate each method individually, not as a whole. This doesn't work either because I'm verifying chars in a string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner isValidEmail = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your email: ");
        String email = isValidEmail.nextLine();

 public static boolean isAlphanumeric(String email) { 
        if (email >= 'a' && email <= 'z' || email >= '0' && email <= '9' || s >= 'A' && email <= 'Z') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

And this for some reason does not work either, which i thought would work!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner isValidEmail = new Scanner(System.in);
    String email = isValidEmail.nextLine();
    isAlphaNumeric();
}

public static boolean isAlphaNumeric(String email) {
    for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {
        char s = email.charAt(i);
        if (s >= 'a' && s <= 'z' || s >= '0' && s <= '9' || s >= 'A' && s <= 'Z')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Etc, etc, per method I need to check against?

Comment: Just for curiosity - why can't you use regex?
One solution i could imagine:
check for alphanumeric strings as you do. but instead of returning a boolean, you return the index where the check stopped. then just do a substring of the string you check and proceed with the next step. would that be an option?

Comment: Not allowed. It's for an intro to Java course, and I'm stuck. That might, but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The only sure way to verify an email address is to send an email, and ask to user to confirm something. As an aside JakartaMail (new name of JavaMail) itself can validate the syntactic validity of an email address for you.

Comment: I don't need to know if the email entered is an actual/real email, I just need to validate it against a certain group of criteria and output true/false PER each criteria. So for example, in my original post, I show validating against 2 of the predetermined criteria (the criteria are:  alphanumeric, valid prefix, valid domain, only contains 1 @) plus I have to extract the prefix and the domain...

The code below works great, but it's all one check to check everything together and give me a true/false to see if the email is valid. I need to break it down.

Answer (score 0):

I had the simple idea to just replace alphanumeric characters by an 'x', and then check if the remaining pattern matches "x@x".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    private static String alphanumericChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your email: ");
        String email = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean isValidEmail = isEmail(email);
        System.out.println(isValidEmail ? "Thank you." : "This is not a valid email.");
    }

    public static boolean isEmail(String str) {
        String pattern = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {      
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            if (isAlphanumeric(c)) {
                if (pattern.length() == 0 || pattern.charAt(pattern.length() - 1) != 'x') {
                    pattern += "x";     // add an x as marker for an alphanumeric string.  
                }
            } else {
                pattern += c;   // add not matching character
            }
        }
        return pattern.equals("x@x");   // check if pattern matches your email-pattern
    }

    public static boolean isAlphanumeric(char c) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < alphanumericChars.length(); i++) {
            if (alphanumericChars.charAt(i) == c)  {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```